# Bottom Half vs. Kernel context in Preemption disabled kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

Quick question.

1. Ethernet driver raise IRQ.
2. ISR will schedule tasklet (BH)
3. There is critical section between this tasklet and some kernel context (which is trigger by "ioctl")
4. KERNEL_PREEMPTION is disabled / But CONFIG_SMP is enabled (2 CPUs)

In this situation, should I use "spin_lock_bh"?

Since preemption is "disabled", even though kernel context holds "spin_lock", tasklet cannot preempt the kernel context which is calling ioctl and this kernel context is kind of "safe" from BH.

or is it possible for following scenario to happen?

When this kernel context is getting serviced, IRQ comes and ISR will schedule tasklet. Then, after returning from IRQ, kernel schedule will pickup tasklet even though there is kernel context.

I'm not sure which one is correct?

Comment: Did you read Rusty's [Unreliable Guide To Locking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/)?

Comment: Yes. It's only covering PREEMPTION enable case or both PREEMPTION and SMP are disabled. What I'm wondering is, CONFIG_SMP=y and No preemption configuration, how softirq is executed.

Comment: The API is the same regardless of configuration.

Comment: I'm only wondering, bottom half can preempt the kernel context (kernel thread which is not in ISR/BH). Also, wondering when ISR schedules BH, it will be executed regardless of current running thread.

Thanks!

Comment: Kernel and 'normal' threads are not different in this regard.

Comment: First of all, appreciate your answer! So, since it's kernel (bh) == normal thread are not different in this context, spin_lock_bh is not really required?

Comment: A thread is not a bottom half.

Comment: Maybe it will help your thought process to turn it around: If you hold a "spinlock" of any kind, you'd better *not* be interrupted *on the same processor* by an ISR/softirq/bottom-half that needs to acquire the same spinlock. OTOH, it's fine to hold the spinlock if the ISR/softirq/bottom-half can only interrupt *another* processor. (Because in the latter case, the ISR/softirq/BH will just spin waiting for you to release the lock.)

Comment: If we disable kernel preemption by changing CONFIG_PREEMPT, bottom half cannot preempt the normal thread (which is coming from syscall() or ioctl()). Right? Then, why do we need spin_lock_bh? That's my major question. 

In general, yes, that's not a very good way to write the code to mixing up spin_lock between bh / thread context but if preemption is disabled, what will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preemption status is irrelevant. Upon return from the ISR, the tasklet could run whether preemption is enabled or disabled. So, yes you need to use `spin_lock_bh()`.

Regarding synchronization issues, SoftIRQs/Tasklets behave like the ISRs, the only difference is that ISRs interrupt BHs. Since the ISR interrupted the kernel while it was holding a lock, so can the tasklet.

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm really thinking for this situation. Only reason to call spin_lock_bh is for the scheduling. However, when ISR is finished, doesn't kernel revert back the previous context?? go ahead for BH processing?

Comment: @user2526111  The second is correct. The  Kernel is allowed to execute the BH after finishing the ISR. This can happen even if the interrupted process held a lock. On another note, you mentioned that there're 2 CPUs, this means you need a spin lock (you can have two processes accessing the critical section concurrently).

Comment: Agree. I definitely need "spin_lock". But, I was wondered.... about local_bh_disable.....

Comment: @user2526111  As I mentioned above, preemption status is irrelevant to IRQs and SoftIRQs/Tasklets. So yes, you also need local_bh_disable. As you know, spin_lock_bh will do both.